# How to check if input is int?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm, x86-16

I have this homework that requires me to ask for two integers from the user, let them choose between addition or subtraction and then display the result. One of the requirements for the assignment is that you must send an error message if the input is invalid. For example, if instead of a number you input a letter or any other character, or if you input any character other than '+' or '-'.

I tried to compare the input to each digit(which I know is not ideal and uses more memory, but couldn't think of anything else) but it didn't work.

```
INPUT OF NUMBER:   

        mov     dx,offset MSG_1     
        mov ah,09h          
        int 21h         

        mov bx,offset VALUE_1   
        call    STRING_INPUT        

        mov bx,offset OUT_DATA_1    
        call    STRING_MOVE 

STRING_INPUT    

        proc    near
        mov ah,0Ah          
        mov dx,offset IN_BUF    
        int 21h         

        mov al,byte ptr[IN_BUF + 1]     
        cmp al,0                
        jbe ST_IN_ERR

        mov al,byte ptr[IN_BUF + 1] 
        mov ah,00h          
        mov si,ax           

        mov word ptr[bx],0      

        mov word ptr[UNIT],1    

STRING_INPUT_LOOP:  

        cmp si,0            
        je  STRING_INPUT_NEXT   

        mov al,byte ptr[IN_BUF + 1 + si]    
        sub al,30h          
        mov ah,0            
        mul word ptr[UNIT]      
        add word ptr[bx],ax     
        dec si          

        mov ax,word ptr[UNIT]   
        mul word ptr[TEN]       
        mov word ptr[UNIT],ax
        jmp STRING_INPUT_LOOP   

STRING_INPUT_NEXT:  
      ret

STRING_INPUT  
      endp
```

The program is supposed to send an error if the input is any character other than a digit, but  when I input a letter, it transform that letter into a value(which I suspect is the hexadecimal value or something of the sorts) and continues as normal. In the code above the part where i tried to compare the value to each digit is not included because I deleted it in a fit of frustration.

Comment: See [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](//stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) for how to check for non-digit characters in your string->int loop.  `sub al, '0'` then `cmp al,9` / `ja non_digit`.

Comment: Classic x86 computer has only "bit" to store value. A bit can have two values (usually "0" or "1" is used to describe it). Register `AL` is ordered group of eight bits. I.e. it can't contain "letter" or "hexa value", that's **interpretation** of the bit pattern stored in AL. Because computers don't have means to store "letters" as letters, the SW does use some kind of encoding particular letter as particular bit pattern, in ASM tutorials usually the ASCII encoding is used (it's simple), i.e. hexa value 0x61, binary 0b01100001 and letter 'a' are just different interpretations of the same value.

Comment: And the other way, the input service of DOS 0x0A does provide user input as sequence of ASCII encoded characters, so when the user enters "integer" `1234`, you receive in the buffer reserved for 0x0A service five bytes: 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x0D (the last one is the "Enter" key, the first four are ASCII encoding of digits 1, 2, 3 and 4). So to create something like "calculator" you have to convert that "string" input into native integer form (16 bits pattern probably makes most sense for a task like this, if you are in 16b real mode of the CPU ... 1234 in binary/bits is `‭0100'1101'0010‬`).